# What is the difference between "there's no" and "there's not"? When to use "not" and when to use "no"?

Tags: negation

As we know, **not** and **no** are different words, which is why I don't know if there is a difference between "there's no" and "there's not".

[This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%27s+no%2C+there%27s+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThere%20%27s%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20%27s%20not%3B%2Cc0) diagram shows that the two forms are used and this makes me think that they are both acceptable.

My question is:  Are they both grammatically correct?  If so, is there any rule regarding the use of one over the other, lest we should use them wrongly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "not a", "no" and "not any"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52397/difference-between-not-a-no-and-not-any)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, As a matter of fact I don't see any difference between my question and the one you linked but the truth is that none of the answers to that question solve my confusion whereas this answer, here, brilliantly solved my problem. So what shall I do next?

Comment: You can still upvote and accept answers if the question is a duplicate and the question will not be deleted.

Comment: Lucian, I agree absolutely agree @Kirt's answer here (which I have upvoted) addresses your question better than any on the "original" - and in fact it's probably a better "generic" answer covering both questions than any of the earlier ones (*none* of which I've upvoted). Catija has the right of it in terms of what *you* can/should do, but possibly a mod might "merge" the two questions. Or if yours *does* get closed, anyone (incl you) could add a link to it on the original. Or Kirt could copy and paste his answer into the original as well (I'd quite happily upvote it *again!* :)

Comment: The other question is being closevoted as a duplicate of this one. Shouldn't we close just one of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forget "no" and "not" for a second - they seem related, but it is a false comparison.

Instead, think about

"There is" vs. "There is not".  These are related expressions but one is positive and one is negative.

Things are simple when the (reflexive) subject of the sentence is *expressed positively*.
For example, suppose the subject is "life".

**There is** (life on Mars).

**There is not** (life on Mars).

The complication is that sometimes the subject is *expressed negatively*.
Suppose the subject was "no life".

The verb-positive sentence remains the same.

**There is** (no life on Mars).

The verb-negative sentence has to change, though, because English (unlike Spanish) has rules against double negatives.

It is **incorrect** to say:

**There is not** (no life on Mars).

Instead, we say

**There is not** (*any* life on Mars).

Other examples of a negative subject becoming positive because the verb is negative:

*There is* no reason to agree with him.  *There is not* **any** reason to agree with him.

*There is* no way out of this situation.  *There is not* **a** way out of this situation.

*There is* no one alive who remembers him.  *There is not* **any**one alive who remembers him.

In each case, the "not" in "There is not" is part of the verb, making the verb negative, whereas the "no" is part of the subject, making the subject negative.  So you can't really compare "there is no" with "there is not" - just remember that in English, you are not allowed to have both the verb and subject expressed negatively.

Comment: It's probably worth explicitly pointing out that syntactically, *There is **no** [noun]* is generally equivalent to *There is **not a** [noun]*. That's to say there needs to be a determiner/article with the ***not*** version. Thus, *There is no god listening to your prayers* can equally be expressed using ***...not a...*** (or ***not some*** in that exact context, but I can't easily explain why ***any*** doesn't work there, whereas it's fine in your similar examples).

Comment: There is no reason.....and there isn't any reason .......mean the same, but negation in  the former is stronger or more emphatic than that in the latter.